# Maximizing a monotonically increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a monotonically increasing function in each of its variables. For instance, this means that for a given $(x_2,\dots,x_n)$, the one dimensional function $f(x_1,\dots)$ will be a monotonically increasing function in $x_1$. Let $g(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be also a monotonically increasing function in each of its variables. Let $B$ be a positive constant. Also let us say that $f(.)$ and $g(.)$ are non-negative functions as well. You can assume continuity and differentiability as well. In addition, assume that there exists at least one point such that $g(x_1,\dots,x_n)=B$. What can we say about the optimization problem \begin{align}\max_{x_1,\dots,x_n}~&~f(x_1,\dots,x_n) \\s.t.&~~g(x_1,\dots,x_n)\leq B\\& ~~x_i\geq 0~,~\forall i\end{align}I am interested to know if there is a general approach to this type of problems.

Comment: You could start with $n=1$. If $g(x)\leq B$ for all $x$, then it's an unconstrained problem and the answer is either $+\infty$ or the limit of $f$ at $+\infty$.

Comment: @anderstood since they both are monotonically increasing function, unconstrained situation will never happen, right?

Comment: What about $g(x)=1-e^{-x}$ for example? It is stricly increasing and always $\leq 1$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Do you want to ask if the maximum is occured at points where $g(x) =B$?

Comment: @JohnMa I want to know is there a general approach to find the solution of this problem...

Comment: The maximum, if it exists,  indeed occurs at the points at which $g(x)=B.$  To see this, assume that $x$ is a solution and $g(x)<B.$ By continuity, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $g(x+\epsilon e_1) \leq B,$ and by the increasing property of $f$ we will have $f(x+\epsilon e_1) >f(x),$ a contradiction.

Comment: I do not believe there is a general approach to this problem. The fact that $g(x)=B$ at the solution probably doesn't help much; after all, if you replace the constraint with $g(x)=B$ you have a nonlinear equality constraint which is even more difficult to deal with in general.

Comment: So the monotonicity doesn't help in any way?

Comment: Define "help". It's still intractable.